# Count occurrence of a particular column value in sqlite, android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a table in which a particular column has a value repeated number of times.
I want to calculate how many times it occur.

Let's say the database has column as "Select" repeated 5 times in the table.
How do I count it?

this is the code I am using

```
    public String getCountSelect() {
    String count = "";
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT ( " + KEY_DEALER_NAME + " )  FROM "
            + TABLE_DEALER + " WHERE " + KEY_DEALER_NAME + " = 'Select'";
    Log.e("", selectQuery);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {


            Log.e("", cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(KEY_DEALER_NAME)));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this way

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT " + KEY_DEALER_NAME + "  FROM "
        + TABLE_DEALER + " WHERE " + KEY_DEALER_NAME + " = 'Select'";

 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

 int total_count=cursor.getCount();
```

**Cursor** `.getCount()` method returns total affected rows.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the returned column is what you have written in the SELECT clause, i.e., `COUNT( DealerName )`.
But this does not matter because you can use the column index, i.e., you know this is column 0.

Anyway, a query with COUNT returns a single value, so you can use a [DatabaseUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html) helper function to make your code simpler.

Finally, `COUNT(*)` is a little bit more efficient:

```java
public long getCountSelect() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        String selectQuery =
                "SELECT COUNT(*)" +
                " FROM " + TABLE_DEALER +
                " WHERE " + KEY_DEALER_NAME + " = 'Select'";
        return DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(db, selectQuery, null);
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fire  your query and it return cursor. And perform .getCount() function on cursor it gives you total value of your query.

**code:-**

```
cursor.getCount();
```